# Oracle sql to query last N rows as rest of dividing by fixed value

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "PIPPO" ("COLUMN1" number);
   
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (8);
```

Is there an "easy" way to run a `SELECT` query on the table to get the last N rows, where N is the rest of divide by 3?

For example for this case I would like o retrieve:

```
7
8
```

Imagine to insert another record

```
   INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (9);
```

In this case, I would like to retrieve:

```
7
8
9
```

Imagine inserting yet another record:

```
   INSERT INTO PIPPO (COLUMN1) VALUES (10);
```

Now in this case I would like to retrieve just:

```
10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _Last_ - according to what?

Comment: order by column1

Comment: But '10' comes between '1' and '2'.

Comment: you are right :)  i'll edit with number column ... it's better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the innermost subquery return the number of rows to return. Use `FETCH FIRST` to get that number of rows:

```
select * from
(
    select * from PIPPO 
    order by COLUMN1 desc
    fetch first (select mod(count(*)-1, 3) + 1 from PIPPO) rows only
) dt
order by COLUMN1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` and use a sub-query to get the `n` value:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   pippo
ORDER BY column1 DESC
FETCH FIRST (SELECT DECODE(MOD(COUNT(*), 3), 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2) FROM pippo) ROWS ONLY
```

or you can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT column1
FROM   (
  SELECT column1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1 DESC) AS rn,
         MOD(COUNT(*) OVER (), 3) AS rem
  FROM   pippo p
)
WHERE  rn <= DECODE(rem, 0, 3, rem);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d1CKpq6s)